# Conversión de tipo date a string en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema asociado con la conversión de un dato. En la base tengo declarado esto:

```
Cuenta.value('FechaApertura[1]','date') FechaApertura
```

y al correr mi procedimiento me dice:

```
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
```

¿Me podrían dar una idea de como resolver esto?

Comment: no se si es un SP o que.. que es FechaApertura[1]?? y por ahi, no es que no deberia estar entre comillas?

Comment: Así es, es un SP.Y 'FechaApertura' es una columna de tipo date de una tabla

Comment: Claro. Pero entonces pq le pasas el nombre de la columan en lugar del dato. No deberia ir sin comillas?

Comment: ¿Es un XML en el que quieres convertir su valor a Date?. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir dicho XML y tu consulta que hiciste.